# Trigger gh-actions workflow run if previous workflow run pushes any changes

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I have a **gh-action** workflow that generates readme files and stores them in the repository's docs folder.

I have another workflow that deploys page-builds and should be triggered if any changes occur in any `README` files in the doc folder.

But the second workflow does not trigger even after the first workflow creates new `README` files and updates the previous ones.

#### build workflow

```
name: build

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

  schedule:
    - cron: "0 */6 * * *"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

        ...

      - name: push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@v0.6.0
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: master
```

#### deploy workflow

```
name: deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - docs/**/*.md

  workflow_dispatch:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Github Official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow)

> When you use the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN` to perform tasks, events triggered by the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, with the exception of workflow_dispatch and repository_dispatch, will not create a new workflow run. **This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive workflow runs.**

The solution is the following recommendation:

> If you do want to trigger a workflow from within a workflow run, you can use a **personal access token** instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN` to trigger events that require a token. You'll need to create a personal access token and store it as a secret.

[Here is how to create a Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)